# Pass @mixin as parameter

Tags: sass

I have a `mixin` that is used in several places. I would like to know if it's also possible to pass this `mixin` as parameter. This is a code sample of mine:

```
.modules-component {
    ion-content {
        &.math {
            @include scroll-content(ocean);

            scroll-content {
                ion-item-group {
                    ion-item:nth-child(3) {
                        @include linear-gradient(to left, color($colors, lagoon) 15%, color($colors, ocean) 100%, color($colors, ocean) 100%);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        &.english {
            @include scroll-content(meadow);

            scroll-content {
                ion-item-group {
                    ion-item:nth-child(3) {
                        @include linear-gradient(to left, color($colors, lemon) 15%, color($colors, meadow) 100%, color($colors, meadow) 100%);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        &.german {
            @include scroll-content(petal);

            scroll-content {
                ion-item-group {
                    ion-item:nth-child(3) {
                        @include linear-gradient(to left, color($colors, lilac) 15%, color($colors, petal) 100%, color($colors, petal) 100%);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you see the `scroll-content` area is always the same **include** except hat the color values are different. How can I simplify the code above?

Answer (score 0):

You could try working with scss `@each` loop and hashes. E.g.:

```
ion-content {
    @each $class, $color in (("english": "meadow"), ("math": "ocean"), ("german": "petal")) {
        &.#{$class} {
            @include scroll-content($color);

            scroll-content {
                ion-item-group {
                    ion-item:nth-child(3) {
                        @include linear-gradient(to left, color($colors, lemon) 15%, color($colors, $color) 100%, color($colors, $color) 100%);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```